# JavaScript Event Flow - When would you use it. Real World Example

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

When would you ever use the Event Flow is an application? What I'm referring to is the third parameter of the `AddEventListener` function. Can anyone provide a real world example?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of reasons to use event capturing instead of event bubbling. Furthermore, event capturing isn't supported in IE8.

For more info, [this page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) deals with the differences between bubbling/capturing.

In practice, the only reason that I can think of to use event capturing is to deal with events that don't bubble, namely `onfocus` and `onblur`. See also this [SO post dealing with `onblur`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525718/event-bubbling-and-the-onblur-event)